# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] in angular v1.3.13

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new at angular.js im trying to build an application and getting Error, Any one please help me to fix this error

> application.js

```
// AngularJS
//= require angular/angular.min
//= require angular/angular-route.min
//= require angular/angular-resource.min
//= require angular/angular-strap.min

//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require controllers/app
//= require controllers/users

//= require services/sessionService
```

> app.js

```
'use strict';
var bugTrackingAngular = angular.module('bugTrackingAngular', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'templates', 'sessionService', '$strap.directives'])
  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');

        var interceptor = ['$location', '$rootScope', '$q', function($location, $rootScope, $q) {
            function success(response) {
                return response
            };

            function error(response) {
                if (response.status == 401) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:unauthorized');
                    $location.path('/users/login');
                    return response;
                };
                return $q.reject(response);
            };

            return function(promise) {
                return promise.then(success, error);
            };
        }];
        $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
  }])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {templateUrl:'home/index.html'})
      .when('/users/login', {templateUrl:'users/login.html', controller: 'UsersCtrl'})
      .when('/users/register', {templateUrl:'users/register.html', controller: 'UsersCtrl'});
  }]);
```

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=bugTrackingAngular…2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fassets%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fbody%3D1%3A18%3A1)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax of that `application.js`; is it saying that this `app.js` is included in your html?

Comment: @pankajparkar it is not in config block

Comment: The `sessionService`, just as wickY26 writes, is NOT in a config block, it is a module dependency. (We cannot tell if it is correctly placed there from the included code, we just hope that there is a `angular.module('sessionService',[...])` somewhere.)

Comment: @user3318090 You need to include the text *after* the ellipsis in the error message for us to see what fails.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Sorry..that's my bad

Comment: it can be cause by angular-strap, I think their module name is 'mgcrea.ngStrap'.

Comment: Thanks for you reply .. Fix this issue by adding 'mgcrea.ngStrap'

Comment: 'responseInterceptors' is deprecated so change '$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor)' to '$httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor)'